# Handling Menu Selection from View Class with MFC(Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, menu, mfc

I'm using Visual Studio and MFC to write a program that will take mouse input from the user to draw a polygon and clip it against a rectangle when the respective menu button is pressed. My problem is, the user input and drawing is handled in the view class(CCssample1View, to be exact), while the menus are in CMainFram class. Even when I define OnMenuSelect function in CCssample1View, it doesn't get notified when a menu button is selected.

Is there a way to associate the menu buttons with the view class so that when they are pressed, the view class' OnMenuSelect function is notified, instead of, or in addition to, that of Main Frame? Or is there another way of handling this problem?

P.S. I literally started using Visual Studio, MFC *and* OpenGL about 6 hours ago, so I might have understood something monumentally wrong.

Update:

Here's the message maps for the view:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCssample1View, CView)


//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CCssample1View)
        ON_WM_CREATE()
        ON_WM_DESTROY()
        ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
        ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
        ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
        ON_WM_SIZE()
        ON_COMMAND(ID_DBL_BUF, OnDblBuf)
        ON_COMMAND(ID_NO_DBL_BUF, OnNoDblBuf)
        //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
        // Standard printing commands
        ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, CView::OnFilePrint)
        ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, CView::OnFilePrint)
        ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, CView::OnFilePrintPreview)
        ON_WM_MENUSELECT()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and the main frame:

```
 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMainFrame)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove mapping macros here.
        //    DO NOT EDIT what you see in these blocks of generated code !
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

creation of the menu(in main frame's OnCreate function):

```
CMenu *menu = new CMenu;
menu->CreateMenu();
menu->AppendMenuA(MF_STRING, 2002, "Clip");
SetMenu(menu);
```

lastly, view's event handler:

```
void CCssample1View::OnMenuSelect(UINT nItemID, UINT nFlags, HMENU hSysMenu)
{
    CView::OnMenuSelect(nItemID, nFlags, hSysMenu);
    while(1);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
}
```

Still, nothing happens when I press the menu button(by that I mean the program runs on without the infinite loop taking effect). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use WM_MENUSELECT?
WM_MENUSELECT is sent only to the main Frame that holds the menu. This Windows message is never routed.

Instead use a WM_COMMAND (ON_COMMAND) handler. WM_COMMAND handlers are routed through the view, Frame, doc and application object according to this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfzay75.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2c310k.aspx

If you want to add a handler for more command items you can use ON_COMMAND_RANGE and others.

PS: You have already ON_COMMAND handler in your code!

Comment: I had no knowledge whatsoever of commands. Thanks for pointing it out. I added the command functions and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Menu commands can be handled in the main frame, or the view, or the document. Just add the appropriate entry in the message map for the class where you want to handle the message. Each command can be handled in one place only, so if you already have a message map entry in the main frame and don't want to handle it there remove the line from the main frame message map.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working. I added the relevant pieces of code to the OP.